# Why would I ever want to have SETNOCOUNT OFF?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL and in my research of best performance I'm seeing everywhere to SET NOCOUNT ON in all of my queries to improve performance... I understand that it returns the rows affected and that's "most of the time" unnecessary data transmission, but my question is when would you want that? If ever? Why is it set to OFF as default? Can I set it to ON by default?

Comment: It depends on your use-case; some ORM libraries make use of it and sometimes require it; presumably you're using SQL Server, you can set it in various places including in SSMS settings query execution > SQL server > Advanced

Comment: Which dbms are you using? That's a product specific feature.

Comment: sorry, I'm very new so don't fully understand these questions...@stu, yes I am using SQL Server. @jarlh I'm using SQL Server Management Studio... is that what you were asking? As far as my web application it's a lead management system to track what users are working with what leads etc. hope that helps.

Comment: _Why is it set to OFF as default_ Because MS must support legacy behavior that was not completely anticipated or intended when functionality was first introduced over the many decades of SQL Server development. It has lots of quirks that make little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain why I use SET NOCOUNT ON and SET NOCOUNT OFF a lot.

I usually interact with the database by loading script files. I set SQL Server Management Studio to display the output as text.

Why do I do this, and why do I use SET NOCOUNT ?

I set the output as text as then I can see very easily what the queries have returned.

I might be sending 20 or 30 queries to the database, and if I return the results as grid makes it really hard to know what has happened, as there are so many tabs to look through.

And why use SET NOCOUNT ?

Well, the main reason is that I've probably deleted some rows, and if I use SET NOCOUNT OFF I can very quickly see whether I've deleted 10,246 rows, when I was only expecting to have deleted 7.

So basically, loading and running commands from a script file, setting the output to text, and setting SET NOCOUNT OFF tells me very quickly whether my commands have done as I expected.

I agree that, if you're not running commands from a text file, and setting output to text, the setting does seem pointless.

For the use case though that I describe, it really is useful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).